# How do you change an image in HTML code using Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, image

```
   function partyimage() {
    var img = "https://clubrunner.blob.core.windows.net/00000050029/Images/party-time-logo.jpg";
    imaage.src = img;
}

 <div id="imaage">
    <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/funny-vector-stick-man-balloon-hat-children-s-style-no-party-event-sign-red-prohibition-stop-symbol-icon-sticker-156024993.jpg" alt="No Party right now" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload =()=>{
    var img = "https://clubrunner.blob.core.windows.net/00000050029/Images/party-time-logo.jpg";
    let image = document.getElementById('imaage').childNodes[1];
    image.setAttribute('src',img);
}
```

```html
<div id="imaage">
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/funny-vector-stick-man-balloon-hat-children-s-style-no-party-event-sign-red-prohibition-stop-symbol-icon-sticker-156024993.jpg" alt="No Party right now" />
</div>
```